# How much data does it take to load an empty url?

Tags: ios, swift, download, urlsession, user-data

I am looping over a couple of urls but only some will give back an image. The other ones are just empty. The urls which give back an image can change daily which is why I want to loop over all urls. I am wondering if loading an empty url takes a significant amount of the users data and would be "bad programming".

I do not think my code is necessary to answer the question but here it is in case it helps.

```
for index in 1..<32{
        let url = URL(string: "https://jarisstoriesphotographyphoto.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/menu\(index).png")!
            // 1.
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index-1)
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
            // 2.
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
            
        getImage(withURL: url) { image in

            imageView.image = image
            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
}
```

my get image function

```
func getImage(withURL url:URL, completion: @escaping (_ image:UIImage?)->()) {
        if let cachedVersion = cache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString) {
            completion(cachedVersion.image)
        } else {
            downloadImage(withURL: url, completion: completion)
        }
    }
```

My downloading function

```
func downloadImage(withURL url:URL, completion: @escaping (_ image:UIImage?)->()) {
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, responseURL, error in
            var downloadedImage:UIImage?

            if let data = data {
                downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)
            }
            
            if downloadedImage != nil {
                let cacheImage = ImageCache()
                cacheImage.image = downloadedImage
                self.cache.setObject(cacheImage, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(downloadedImage)
            }
            
        }
        
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean here by "empty URL?" That can have a lot of meanings. Do you mean it returns an HTTP 404 error? 204 NO CONTENT? A zero-sized PNG? A 200, along with no data What is "empty?" (When I try to access the URLs generated by your example code, I get 404.) What alternative are you comparing this approach to? If we said "yes, that's horrible," what would you change?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. It is a "404 file not found" when no image can be downloaded. So far I want to update the images very time the app appears for the first time in a day to see if new images are available. If you would say that solution is horrible I would try use push notification to trigger an update.

Comment: If these change rarely, then a push notification would be a win, not because of the size of the response, but because of the fairly large cost of setting up a network request to the server, particularly if there are no other network requests. Making the first network request has to warm up a lot of power hungry things, and creating a TLS pipe to a server is also pretty expensive. Depending on the server, those pipes can be reused, making the second request much cheaper. So if you can get down to zero, that's a big win. If you're making a bunch of requests, one more small one isn't a big deal.

Comment: Another approach, if push notifications are a hassle or costly (and the data doesn't need to be always up to date), is to use a BGAppRefreshTaskRequest to periodically check things. The system will do a lot of power management for you in that case, and only call you when it's most appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple check would be to check what the "empty" response returns.

Using curl on the command line will tell you the sizes of the request (what your users are sending), and the headers and download size of the response.

```
curl --compressed -w '%{size_request} %{size_header} %{size_download}' http://example.com/
```

That will output 3 numbers (in bytes) after the response data. Testing against an example of the URL in your code sample that returns `404` outputs `160 263 761`.

So roughly speaking, each empty URL uses ~1.15 kB of data (this depends on the exact compression used, and other variables, depending on the server).